# Como deixar o texto do parágrafo interno da div sem o sublinhado?

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Estou estudando sobre classes e ids e me deparei com esse problema abaixo. Seria possível deixar somente o "TEXTO ESCONDIDO" sem o sublinhado?

```css
div:hover{            
  color: rgb(96, 96, 226); 
  text-decoration: underline;                      
}        

div > p {
  display: none;  
}

div:hover > p{
  display: block;            
  background-color: rgb(226, 171, 70);
  color: rgb(80, 19, 179);
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 250px;            
}
```

```html
<h1>Exemplo de hover</h1>
<p>Passe o mouse sobre o texto abaixo</p>
<div>
  Passe o mouse aqui
  <p>TEXTO ESCONDIDO...</p>
</div>
```

Já tentei o seguinte:

```css
div:hover > p {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Tentei criar ids, classes e utilizar inline CSS, mas nada funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez, manter o texto relativo ao *call-to-action* "solto" dentro do `div` impossibilite isso. Tente colocar o texto dentro de uma tag `span` e colocar as diretivas de `text-decoration` no CSS para que sejam direcionadas ao span apenas:

```css
div:hover > span {            
  color: rgb(96, 96, 226); 
  text-decoration: underline;                      
}        

div > p {
  display: none;
}

div:hover > p {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(226, 171, 70);
  color: rgb(80, 19, 179);
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Exemplo de hover</h1>
<p>Passe o mouse sobre o texto abaixo</p>
<div>
  <span>Passe o mouse aqui</span>
  <p>TEXTO ESCONDIDO...</p>
</div>
```